# configure networking between vm on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I installed virtual box on my window 7 laptop, when i install new vm and install ubuntu os,now when i choose nat everything works fine when i am unable to configure host-only network on it .

and one more problem i am facing when i clone that machine and start it and change mac address from setting and start sometime no network configured on the machine .

i actually want to start two vm on virtual box ,both machine have 2 network adapter 1 for nat to communicate any where and one for host and local vms. if is possible or not if yes tell me configuration . i already tried solution from googling no luck still  .

Comment: Can you be more spesific than "everything works fine" and "unable to configure". Reading between the lines i get the feeling that you have internet access as your main criteria for success. In that case, your problem with host-only configuration might be that it is indeed host-only (no internet access). To get the vm's online you have to configure internet sharing on the host-only adapter in windows. Host-only is also the correct choice for your 2nd set of adapters (but this time without internet sharing enabled).

Comment: Hi ,i created two vm using virtual box , now i want to establish communication between two vm with host os.

Comment: The host-only type of adapter is supposed to do that. That is, the vm's + host can all talk to eachother when configured to use host-only adapters. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Comment: hi ,this is the problem , i tried this method ,not luck till time .

Comment: hi all, when i restart my vm it always change ethn menas sometime eth0 sometime eth1, how to fix this .later when i configured ip address on it and

Comment: hi ,i found the solution , we can use bridge  networking .after this i got solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution , we can use bridge networking/host -only networking  for establish communication channel among vms and host os

we can use nat for one n/w adapter and we choose either  bridge networking or host -only on another adapter .
nat for connecting vm to internet
bridge networking/host -only  -- communication among vms and host machine

Comment: You should include your solution so that other people can learn from it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that using only "Host-only Networking".
Setup is as follows:

Host:
At least 1 Host-only Network is present and configured, e.g.
- ip address is set to: 192.168.56.1
- dhcp server: enabled or disabled (works on both)
Note the name of the Host-only network, e.g. "vboxnet0". This will be used in the next steps.

Guest VM 1:
1. Set Adapter 1 (or any other adapters) to "Host-only Adapter".
2. Make sure Name is set to the name noted in the Host section above, e.g. "vboxnet0".

Guest VM 2 (same steps with Guest VM 1):
1. Set Adapter 1 (or any other adapters) to "Host-only Adapter".
2. Make sure Name is set to the name noted in the Host section above, e.g. "vboxnet0".

You can now start your VMs, and verify connectivity by pinging.
Note that if you are using Windows, you must disable firewall or just enable network sharing and discovery.

Comment: On my Windows 10 VM I additionally had to manually set my IP address as the other VMs also had static IP. Make sure they are in the same subnet.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1-if you have firewall switch it off
2. do a bridged network using you primary adapter.
3. use static IP on both

it will work just did and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

- ## Adding more details :

  ## open vmware

  click on file --> preference-->  network-->  Host-only Networks
     Step 1 :Click on add and give a name lets say : Virtual Host-only Ethernet Adapter
     select tab:
     Adapter : 192.168.92.1 (we can select ip range own)
     Ipv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

  ## without this it will also work ,For safe side configure dhcp too:

  select tab --> DHCP Server
     Server Address : 192.168.92.1
     Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
     Lower Address Bound : 192.168.92.2
     Upper Address Bound : 192.168.92.200

  ## VM Machine level configuration:

  Adapter1 : enable this adapter for NAT
     Adapter2 : Enable Network Adapter --> select this checkbox
     Attached to : Host-only Adapter
     Name: Virtual Host-only Ethernet Adapter( name get from Step 1)

  ## on linux machine :

  ### 2nd network interface configuration, eth1

  #append below line in networking conf : /etc/network/interfaces
     auto eth1
     iface eth1 inet dhcp

  ## for statics:

  #append below line in networking conf : /etc/network/interfaces
     auto eth1
     iface eth1 inet static
     address 192.168.92.5
     #gateway 192.168.92.1
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 192.168.92.255
     network 192.168.92.0