# How to get apt working on a nested Ubuntu VM running on GCP?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, apt

I have a nested Ubuntu VM running on a GCP instance.  When I use Firefox I can go to certain websites like Google and The Washington Post. However, when I try to run `apt-get update` from the nested VM terminal, I get a `Connection Failed` error. What I find odd is that when I run `apt-get install` from the GCP instance the update runs fine. Is this a firewall issue? Or, does Google restrict apt IPs and other IP addresses from being called from the nested VM?

Comment: @Daniel Kaminski have you checked if nested virtualization if it is allowed in your GCP? Check this link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/nested-virtualization/managing-constraint#checking_whether_nested_virtualization_is_allowed What OS does your Ubuntu VM was hosted to? Have you checked it's the OS firewall?

Comment: @FierceScarf Did you configure the network connection to the VM? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486971/configure-networking-between-vm-on-virtualbox

Comment: Yes @Daniel Kaminski the VM has access to the internet.

Comment: @FierceScarf I just want to verify, does your nested Ubuntu VM can now connect to the internet?

Comment: @BryanL thank you for asking. I figured out the problem with the apt packages. The problem was I needed to update the url apt was using. But there still seems to be something strange going on with the internet connection. When I curl google sites such as Google.com or Youtube there is no connection issue. However if I do a  test curl to other sites like for instance reddit I get a timeout.

Comment: @FierceScarf good to hear that you were able to figure out the apt packages. Could you post your solution here as an answer, It might help also other community members that may encounter that dilemma. As for your other concern you can create another topic thread, since it is an isolated case.